# In Hibernate using update but still going for a create table

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate in my project. I am getting `create table` queries at my logs,

But I am using a `HBM2DDL_AUTO="update"`

What else could had been missed ?

PS: I get these logs only when the tables are already present at runtime. If tables not present, it obviously runs smooth.

Here are the properties

```
Properties settings = new Properties();
settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "org.postgresql.Driver");
settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:postgresql://" + jdbc_host + ":5432/" + jdbc_database + "?prepareThreshold=0");
settings.put(Environment.USER, jdbc_user);
settings.put(Environment.PASS, jdbc_password);
settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
```

Error Logs:

```
[INFO ]: org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[INFO ]: org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3add81c4
[WARN ]: org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl - HHH000069: Duplicate generator name wca_seq_generator
[WARN ]: org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl - HHH000069: Duplicate generator name wca_seq_generator
[WARN ]: org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl - HHH000069: Duplicate generator name wca_seq_generator
[INFO ]: org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@59696551] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
[WARN ]: org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table WCA_MESSAGE_AUDIT (id int8 not null, createts times
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table WCA_MESSAGE_AUDIT (id int8 not null, create
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked postgresql in java but I've worked with MySQL. And Whenever' I need to create the table using hibernate then I mention the follow feature in application.properties and it allow to create the table. please once go for it and if it still doesn't work please inform me. Put it in proprerties.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update